# How to get rid of submenu tooltips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

When hovering over an menu item with submenu pages in the wordpress backend a "tooltip" showing each submenu page is popping up.

How can I get rid of these?

[image]

What I've tried so far: Removing the `wp-has-submenu` style class. This works - kinda. When hovering the tooltip doesnt appear anymore. On mousedown on an item the tooltip still appears.

```
    $('#adminmenu').children('li').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('wp-has-submenu');
    // removing or changing the value of the 'aria-haspopup' attr doesn't solve the problem. Not sure what the attr is for
    //  $(this).children('a').each(function(){
    //      $(this).attr('aria-haspopup', 'false');
    //  });
    });
```

### Update1

Well okay this seems to be pure javascript and no jQuery. I've removed any event bindings from any element. Still showing tooltips.

```
    $('html').find("*").each(function () {
        $(this).off();
        $(this).unbind();
    });
```

AFAIK and a short google you can't remove pure js event handlers without a reference to the actual handler.

### Update2

Hmm looking through `/wp-admin/js/` it seems everything or at least very much is done in jQuery.. So.. I'm running out of ideas

### Update3

After searching/looking and editing a lot of .js files I decided to delete  `/wp-admin/js` and `/wp-includes/js`. IT IS STILL APPEARING. Holy .. what the heck are they doin.

### Update 4

This seems to work

```
.js #adminmenu .opensub .wp-submenu {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: that should work even without jquery. try manipulating css... like `display:none!important;`

Comment: @Reigel I guess this is not possible since it doesn't create a new submenu. It just *moves* the menu. This means `display: none` will hide it even in collapsed state

Answer (score -1):

Yes,your code is working now. But I 'm describing here a simple way for adding this code in our theme and it will remove the hover effect in admin section. 

Follow the steps.

```
Step-1: add this code in functions.php file of your theme.

function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-hovermenu', get_template_directory_uri() ."/admin.css" );
}add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

Step:2 Create a file named admin.css and add this line in that file.
.js #adminmenu .opensub .wp-submenu {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Now it will works.If need anything else then please let me know.